# "Read comments and add your's" OR "Read comments and add yours"

Tags: apostrophe

I am creating a website. Before the comment section, I have added the following sentence:

**Read comments and add your's.**

But one of my colleagues suggested that it should be "yours", without the apostrophe. Is he right?

Comment: [Oxford Dictionaries Online](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/your): "Note that neither *your* nor *yours* should be written with an apostrophe."

Comment: Here's a link to a table of the possessive pronouns. None of the seven forms (used without noun) has an apostrophe. https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/pronouns-possessive.htm

Comment: And what's with the downvotes? Jeez people! English is not everyone's first language. Some of us are trying to learn and care about English enough to ask before making even a smallest mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pronoun forms *yours, his, hers, ours,* and *theirs* are not written with an apostrophe.